# Searched CASE WHEN processing order

Tags: sql, case-when

I need some information about processing order of the *Searched* `CASE WHEN` statement in SQL.

For example:

```
(CASE
     WHEN Cells.Type <> 'UOM' THEN 0
     WHEN Template_Colors.Uom_Case = 'ONE' THEN 1
     WHEN Template_Colors.Uom_Case = 'MUL' THEN 2
 END) AS CELL_WHAT_UOM
```

I need the result to be always `0`, unless `Cells.Type <> 'UOM'`.

I know that SQL parsers usually proceed from the bottom to the top, but in Oracle the query seems to work correctly, so I suppose that `WHEN` clauses are processed in the order they are.

It is **100% guaranteed** that the `0` case is processed before the others?

Or I have compulsorily to write:

```
(CASE
     WHEN Cells.Type <> 'UOM' THEN 0
     WHEN Cells.Type = 'UOM' AND Template_Colors.Uom_Case = 'ONE' THEN 1
     WHEN Cells.Type = 'UOM' AND Template_Colors.Uom_Case = 'MUL' THEN 2
 END) AS CELL_WHAT_UOM
```

...?

I need this information about Oracle 10g + SQL server 2008 r2 + Postgre.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `Cells.Type` is not equal to `UOM`, you're guaranteed that the result will be 0.

What you are *not* guaranteed (certainly in SQL Server) is that any *expressions* in the other branches will not be computed.

So, if you did the following:

```
CASE WHEN a = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 10/a END
```

You might get a division by zero error.

---

And, even in your example:

```
WHEN Cells.Type = 'UOM' AND Template_Colors.Uom_Case = 'ONE' THEN ...
```

There is *no* guarantee on the order in which predicates are evaluated, so `Template_Colors.Uom_Case` may still be accessed. Not sure what your concern is around whether this column is accessed or not, so no further advice to offer at the present moment.

---

[SQL Server documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

> - Evaluates, in the order specified, *Boolean_expression* for each `WHEN` clause.
> - Returns *result_expression* of the first *Boolean_expression* that evaluates to `TRUE`.
> - If no *Boolean_expression* evaluates to `TRUE`, the Database Engine returns the *else_result_expression* if an `ELSE` clause is specified, or a `NULL` value if no `ELSE` clause is specified.

[Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm):

> In a searched `CASE` expression, Oracle searches from left to right until it finds an occurrence of *condition* that is true, and then returns *return_expr*. If no *condition* is found to be true, and an `ELSE` clause exists, Oracle returns *else_expr*. Otherwise, Oracle returns `null`.

[PostGre](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-conditional.html):

> If the result is true then the value of the `CASE` expression is the result that follows the condition. If the result is false any subsequent `WHEN` clauses are searched in the same manner.

[Ansi 92 (draft)](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt):

> If the `<search condition>` of some `<searched when clause>` in
>                 a `<case specification>` is true, then the value of the `<case
>                 specification>` is the value of the `<result>` of the first
>                 (leftmost) `<searched when clause>` whose `<search condition>` is
>                 true, cast as the data type of the `<case specification>`.

Comment: Thanks, that's not my case. I only need *the result* to be guaranteed.

Comment: No worry about whether this column is accessed or not. Modified my answer to better reflect that.

Comment: @Teejay - I've added the SQL Server documentation

Comment: Thanks, missed that on the SQL server doc page!

Comment: @Teejay - also added Oracle, PostGre and (just for completeness) the ANSI-92 standard. :-)

Comment: Accepted your very complete answer!